# Google Cloud CDN is not logging for Serverless Negs

Tags: google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-cdn

I am using Google Cloud CDN with my HTTPS Load Balancer, with Cloud Run as my backend service. It's all working fine, and assets are being served from the CDN. I can verify the cache hits  via a cUrl command, and seeing the "Age" header increase in time.

But - these hits (Google Cloud CDN) aren't producing any logs.

If I look at the monitoring tab for my URL map on my CDN, I get the following message in the section where the graph should be:

```
"Traffic flow will display here once the backend service receives traffic"
```

My CDN has been up for a whole week already.

When I follow this article: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/logging
When I got my Log View page to build a query, the following resource is not available to select from:

```
"Cloud HTTP Load Balancer > All forwarding rules"
```

When I follow this article: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring

I cannot see the checkbox

```
"Enable logging"
```

[image]

I can also see on my "Backend service details" screen that logging is switched off (bottom of screenshot), but when I Edit it there is no option for me to switch it on ....

[image]

My conclusion is that there are no CDN logs being generated, and that something is not set up correctly. But I don't know where else to look, as CDN logging is supposed to happen automatically.

What else can I do?

This is the documentation I followed to set up a serverless neg hooked up to a load balancer and CDN.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs

Comment: Logging is not enabled by default on backend services: see https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#enabling_logging_on_an_existing_backend_service for how to enable them. Are you checking the Backend Service section of the console?

Comment: Yes - I can see that in the documentation, but there is no where in the frontend where I can see to turn on logging. I'll attach the screenshots ...

Comment: I've updated the title of the post to better reflect that this is very specifically to do with "serverless negs". Because when I try to set a Backend Type in the dropdown (which is blank - I set up the serverless neg via the CLI), for example "Internet Network Endpoint", I can see the logging options appear, but I can't select/find my serverless neg in the next selection box. So perhaps CDN logging isn't available for serverless negs? Even though the CDN itself seems to function when I use cUrl ...

Answer (score 1):

Because serverless negs as a backend to HTTP(S) Load Balancing is actually still in **Beta**, the Console isn't fully functional for this setup.

So to enable logging for this configuration, you'll need to use the *gcloud CLI* to enable logging.

```
gcloud compute backend-services update BACKEND_SERVICE \
    --global \
    --enable-logging \
    --logging-sample-rate=VALUE
```

The Edit Backend Service Details page still doesn't look right, in terms of the dropdown for Backend Type being blank.

But on the View Backend Service Details page, I can now see that logging has been **enabled*.

I got the command from this page:
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring